# (AIR iOS) NetStream.play() blocks microphone access in a Native Extension

Tags: ios, air, microphone, netstream, air-native-extension

We have an AIR Mobile application (iOS) that uses a Native Extension for capturing microphone input. We would like to be able to play a NetStream in the application **and** capture the mic at the same time.

Microphone capture in the Native Extension works fine until we do `NetStream.play()` in the host AIR application. Once that happens, we start receiving zero samples (i.e. silence) in the Native Extension.

We've tried setting `AudioSession` in the ANE and other tricks, but to no avail. Is there a way for AIR Mobile not to block microphone operation in our ANE?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a conflict where AIR SDK audio class override the audio session used by the ANE. Take a look here http://forums.adobe.com/message/5660732 where they provide a workaround by playing the sound using also an ANE

Comment: Thank you. Playing the sound through ANE isn't an option for us because we need to play live audio + video sent from a desktop via a NetStream. So we have to use `NetStream.play()` for that.